# scanf in while loop only works on first iteration

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I am writing a program to analyze memory dumps left by an emulator that I am writing. You can input a memory address and the size of the value you wish to view in order to view the contents of the memory dump.

I have the code running in a while loop, but it only works properly once. When inputting the second memory address to view, it prints out that I have entered an invalid data type, when the input is in fact formatted correctly.

```
uint32_t address = 0;
char read_size = 0;

    printf("%% ");
    scanf("%c %x", &read_size, &address);

    while(read_size != 'q')
    {
        emu_error = 0;

        switch(read_size)
        {
            case 'q':
                goto end;
                break;
            case 'b':
            {
                BYTE b = get_byte_at_ram_address(ram, address);

                if(emu_error != 0)
                    printf("Error: Unable to retrieve byte from that address.\n");
                else
                    printf("BYTE 0x%x: 0x%x, %d\n", address, b, b);

                break;
            }
            case 'w':
            {
                WORD c = get_word_at_ram_address(ram, address);

                if(emu_error != 0)
                    printf("Error: Unable to retrieve byte from that address.\n");
                else
                    printf("WORD 0x%x: 0x%x, %d\n", address, c, c);

                break;
            }
            case 'd':
            {
                DWORD d = get_dword_at_ram_address(ram, address);

                if(emu_error != 0)
                    printf("Error: Unable to retrieve byte from that address.\n");
                else
                    printf("DWORD 0x%x: 0x%x, %d\n", address, d, d);

                break;
            }
            default:
            {
                printf("Error: Data type unrecognized.\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        printf("%% ");
        scanf("%c %x", &read_size, &address);
    }

    end:

    return 0;
```

The program outputs as follows:

```
Allocated 4096 bytes of RAM.
% d FF
DWORD 0xff: 0x100, 256
% d 103
Error: Data type unrecognized.
% Error: Data type unrecognized.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `'\n'` left by the previous `scanf()` like this

```
scanf(" %c %x", &read_size, &address);
/*     ^ tell scanf to skip white spaces with the %c specifier */
```

also do not ignore `scanf()`'s return value, it might cause very weird things in case it fails and you fail to detect that.

Comment: Wow. It seems that `scanf` is really finicky. Thanks for pointing that out. It works now

Comment: @Igor `scanf()` is a pain in fact, it's better to `fgets()` and parse the input later. Did it work?

Comment: `scanf()` is very, *very*, **very**, ***very*** hard to use correctly in all its details.  I'd really rather beginners were not taught it.  The trouble is that for some inputs -- especially those without any malformed data -- it is quite convenient.  But it more often causes trouble than not.  `sscanf()` (often used with `fgets()` is much better; at least you have the input and can rescan it if something goes wrong, unlike plain `scanf()`.